# Time vs Impermanence

Tags: impermanence, insight, time

What is the connection between time and impermanence ? Are they different terms for the same thing ? I heard this from philosopher, "*Nibbana is like a timeless space*".

Comment: A related topic: "[Does the Buddha speak of the nature of time, vis-à-vis “past,” “future,” and “present?”](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/9664/254)"

Answer (score 5):

> What is the connection between time and impermanence ? Are they different terms for the same thing ?

The two are very different concepts. Time can be thought of as the conceptualization of experience as a sequence of events. First this happens then this. Past, present, and future. Impermanence is a separate concept describing the fleeting nature of experience. Experiences such as emotion, the senses, material objects, and even life itself can be said to have a beginning and end and are thus, impertinent.

> I heard this from philosopher, "Nibbana is like a timeless space".

The speaker is trying to describe their experience of the ultimate nature of reality. They are trying to describe Nibbana, the experience that can only be had by seeing through the illusion of form.

In a very incomplete way, Nibbana can be thought of as the canvas on which all of the universe is painted. Imagine you are holding in your hands a photograph. When you look at the photo, you identify your favorite pocket watch within the image. In reality, there is no watch in your hands. You simply have a mental model of what a pocket watch is, and the paper and ink on the page has created the illusion that you are observing a pocket watch you have seen before. For the sake of explanation, one could say “the pocket watch arises out of the photograph”. Without the photograph, you would be unable to observe the watch.

Nibbana and time have the same correlation. Nibbana is like the photograph, and time is like the watch. In our experience, we believe we observe the past, present, and future. We see patterns that we identify as something real, creating a conceptual model that, when it becomes useful in predicting experience, we believe to fundamentally be a part of reality. In reality though, there is only Nibbana. For the sake of explanation, one could say “Time arises out of Nibbana”. Because of this, Nibbana can be described as “timeless”. When observing Nibbana, you do not observe time. For when you observe Nibbana, you are observing the universe before arising/creation occurs. All things that arise from Nibbana are impertinent, including time.

I hope my answer was helpful to you! I pray for nothing more than your liberation this lifetime. =]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you can understand impermanence as an insight into time being a perceptual construct fashioned by the filter of identity/ignorance.